# How to add external jar files to gradle build script

Tags: gradle

Now I use gradle as my build tool. One of my tasks needs to access to a mysql database. Following is my gradle script:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files('/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar')
    }
}


task connectToDb << {
    def props = [user: 'user', password: 'password', allowMultiQueries: 'true'] as Properties
    def url = 'jdbc:mysql://mysqlhost:3306/db'
    def driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, props, driver)

    sql.eachRow('show tables') { row ->
        println row[0]
    }
}
```

I try to run it in a Ubuntu Lucid box but it always fails. The gradle complains with the information: 
Execution failed for task ':connectToDb'.
Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

It seems that the build script doesn't include the mysql connector jar library.Can anyone please tell me how to configure the external jar file properly ? Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This works for me. See this thread about why http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/using-jdbc-driver-in-a-task-fails-td1435189.html:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
configurations {
    driver
}
dependencies {
    driver group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.16'
}

URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader
configurations.driver.each {File file ->
    loader.addURL(file.toURL())
}

task connectToDb << {
    def props = [user: 'user', password: 'password', allowMultiQueries: 'true'] as Properties
    def url = 'jdbc:mysql://mysqlhost:3306/db'
    def driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, props, driver)

    sql.eachRow('show tables') { row ->
        println row[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer fixed a similar problem for me and prompted me to write [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763112/running-groovy-script-from-gradle-using-groovyshell-exception-in-thread-main).

Answer (score 10):

I've had luck with something like this:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath fileTree(dir: '/usr/share/java',
            includes: ['mysql-connector-java.jar'])
    }
}
```

Frankly, though, in your situation I'd prefer this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you for your answer. I have tried both your suggestions but they both failed. Then I created a soft link of mysql-connector-java.jar in $GRADLE_HOME/lib/, and it works. So what could the problem be ? Or could you please give me some hints ? By the way, the version of my gradle is 0.9.1 . Thank you again.

Comment: How something fails is sometimes more important than just knowing that it failed.  Please update your question to indicate the specifics.

Comment: This was pretty simple ! Not sure why the other answer got more votes? My context: Trying to use Liquibase plugin for Oracle

Comment: The answer here cannot have been tested - it doesn't work because the classloader where the SQL driver gets loaded is not the correct "root" classloader. And the solution of linking in the lib in root - which accomplishes that of loading into the root classloader - is obviously not self-contained (you cannot just check out the project and build it, you have to mess with your local Gradle installation, i.e. a definite non-solution).

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet works well for connecting and querying database in **Microsoft SQL SERVER**. Please note that Microsoft does not make jar file 'sqljdbc42.jar'(which is jdbc driver) available on any online repo like MavenCentral(). Therefore, you would need to download this jar from Microsoft's website and save in project workspace directory. 
[Download 'sqljdbc_4.2.6420.100_enu.exe'](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=11774)

Unzip the downloaded file and go to **Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.2 for SQL Server-->sqljdbc_4.2-->enu**. Here you will see the file *sqljdbc42.jar*. Copy the file into project workspace. I copied into dir name **'lib'**.

```
            repositories {
                flatDir name: 'localRepository', dirs: 'lib'
            }
            configurations {
                driver
            }
            dependencies {
                driver group: 'sql', name: 'sqljdbc42', version:''
            }


            URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader
            configurations.driver.each { File file ->
                loader.addURL(file.toURL())
            }

            task connectToCoreDb << {
                def props = [user: 'sa', password: 'shock', allowMultiQueries: 'true'] as Properties
                def connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://cpt-op-01-db1:1433;databaseName=buds"
                def driver = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
                def sql = Sql.newInstance(connectionUrl, props, driver)
                sql.eachRow('SELECT name, alias, expiry_date FROM [buds].[dbo].[obj_keystore] ) { row ->
                    println "$row.name $row.alias $row.expiry_date"
                }
                logger.info "Closing connection..."
                sql.close()
            }
```