# Gradle: cannot execute sql, driver not found

Tags: gradle

I have got the following `gradle` script. It results in `No suitable driver found` error which I found strange.

```
buildscript {
    repositories{
        maven {
            url = 'http://localhost:8090/nexus/content/groups/public/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4.0'
    }
}

task sql << {
    def url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@' + project.properties['db_hostname'] + ':' + project.properties['db_port'] + ':' + project.properties['db_sid']
    println 'sql, db url:' + url
    def driverName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
    Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
    groovy.sql.Sql sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(
            url,
            project.properties['db_username'],
            project.properties['db_password'],
            driverName
    )
}
```

***The error is:***

```
Tasks to be executed: [task ':sql']
:sql (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:sql
Executing task ':sql' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
truncating, db url:jdbc:oracle:thin:@LOCALHOST:1521:orcl
:sql FAILED
:sql (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.105 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/fran/projects/jua/build.gradle' line: 49

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sql'.
> No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@LOCALHOST:1521:orcl

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver jar is being loaded in a different classloader context than the Sql class.  To fix it, try adding this:

```
// Add jars resolved by buildscript classpath configuration to the classloader which Sql will use 
URLClassLoader loader = groovy.sql.Sql.class.classLoader
project.buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { File file ->
  loader.addURL(file.toURL())
}
```

prior to the call to `Sql.newInstance()`.  It will make all your classpath dependencies available to the Groovy classloader which loads the `Sql` class.  The `Class.forName()` should not be neccesary.

See the discussion here for more information: 
http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/using-jdbc-driver-in-a-task-fails-td1435189.html

Answer (score 0):

For me that didn't work (Gradle 2.12).

But instead of performing:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver")
```

I did:

```
groovy.sql.loadDriver("org.h2.Driver")
```

The Groovy `Sql.loadDriver` method does some nifty classloader stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
    configurations {
       db2database
    }

    buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath('com.ibm.db2:db2jcc4:10.5.5')//db2 driver for gradle task
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            db2database "com.ibm.db2:db2jcc4:10.5.5" //db2 driver for configuration
        }

        //load drivers for gradle tasks
        configurations.db2database.each {
            GroovyObject.class.classLoader.addURL(it.toURI().toURL())
        }

        ....
        Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(
                        envProps.getProperty('dbUri'),
                        envProps.getProperty('dbUsername'),
                        envProps.getProperty('dbPassword'),
                        envProps.getProperty('dbDriverClassName')
                )

                println sql.rows("SELECT * FROM TEST.TEST")
```