# Gradle can't load Oracle driver

Tags: oracle, gradle

I need to load the Oracle driver.  Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690923/gradle-build-gradle-dependencies-oracle-driver?rq=1) here is my build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    flatDir name: 'localRepository', dirs: 'lib'
}

configurations {
    driver
}

task loadOracle() << {
    URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader
    configurations.driver.each {File file ->
        loader.addURL(file.toURL())
    }
    Class driverClass = loader.loadClass('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver')
    java.sql.Driver driverInstance = driverClass.newInstance()
    java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(driverInstance)

 //   Sql sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc-url','username','password')
}
```

It gives this Exception:

```
Execution failed for task ':loadOracle'.
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

The line it complains about is

```
Class driverClass = loader.loadClass('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver')
```

It looks like it's just not loading the lib/ojdbc-14.jar file.

A lot of other people have had trouble loading the Oracle driver in gradle.  What does it take?

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem when writing database tasks, due to Groovy's classloader. I found that `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(driver)` worked. Gradle plugins don't exhibit this problem, so I wrote plugins for [jOOQ](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-jooq-plugin) and [flyway](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-flyway-plugin) to deal with my database use-cases.

Comment: I added a println file to the closure, and it's not loading the .jar files from the lib/ directory.  I never thought I'd say this but gradle makes me miss maven.

Answer (score 2):

It is more convenient to declare the Oracle library as [dependency for your build script](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec%3aexternal_dependencies). Here's one way of doing it:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'lib'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath ':ojdbc:14'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved it, after more than 4 hours of drudgery:

```
task verifyDb << {

    def props = new Properties()
    new File("src/test/resources/liquibase.properties").withInputStream { stream ->
        props.load(stream)
    }

    URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader
    loader.addURL ( new File('lib/ojdbc6.jar').toURL() )
    Class driverClass = loader.loadClass('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver')
    java.sql.Driver driverInstance = driverClass.newInstance()
    java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(driverInstance)

    groovy.sql.Sql sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(
        props.url, 
        props.username, 
        props.password)

}
```

The file ojdbc6.jar should be in $PWD/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Try `file.toURI().toURL()` instead of `file.toURL()`. As to the general situation, `java.sql.DriverManager` has known problems when being used from languages other than Java. That's why it's necessary to employ class loader hacks like the above. Using JDBC from a binary Gradle plugin written in Java should work fine. You could also try with an Ant task (which amounts to the same thing). So, just stop hacking JDBC in the build script.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening for me also. I was developing a web application with Spring boot. I added the mysql dependencies and tested with mysql. It worked. Then i tried adding oracle dependency

> runtime('oracle:ojdbc7:12.1.0.2')

I tried running it, but oracle was not loaded by gradle and i got the error that the driver class was not found. I trying for hours, i commented the mysql dependency and then tried refreshing the gradle dependency. It loaded the dependency.