# Running Groovy script from Gradle using GroovyShell: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException

Tags: groovy, gradle

I want to run a groovy command-line script from my Gradle build script.

I'm using this code in my Gradle script:

```
def groovyShell = new GroovyShell();
groovyShell.run(file('script.groovy'), ['arg1', 'arg2'] as String[])
```

Things work fine until my Groovy script (script.groovy) uses the CliBuilder class. Then I get the following exception:

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException

I found lots of people with similar problems and errors, but "the solution" was difficult to extract from the numerous posts I read. Lots of people suggested putting the commons-cli jar on the classpath, but doing so for the GroovyShell was not at all apparent to me. Also, I had already declared @Grapes and @Grab for my required libraries in the script.groovy, so it should have everything it needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [this unaccepted SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6519142/544130), I finally found what I needed to do:

```
//define our own configuration
configurations{
    addToClassLoader
}
//List the dependencies that our shell scripts will require in their classLoader:
dependencies {
    addToClassLoader group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.2'
}
//Now add those dependencies to the root classLoader:
URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader
configurations.addToClassLoader.each {File file ->
    loader.addURL(file.toURL())
}

//And now no more exception when I run this:
def groovyShell = new GroovyShell();
groovyShell.run(file('script.groovy'), ['arg1', 'arg2'] as String[])
```

You can find more details about classLoaders and why this solution works [in this forum post](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/using-jdbc-driver-in-a-task-fails-td1435189.html).

Happy scripting!

*(Before you downvote me for answering my own question, [read this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))*

Comment: This hack shouldn't be required to solve your problem. The forum post you link to is different in that it has to deal with the class loading peculiarities of `java.sql.DriverManager`.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't be necessary @PeterNiederwieser based on my limited understanding of classLoaders! However, it's the only way I've found to make it work. I commented more down below in Hiery's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763112/running-groovy-script-from-gradle-using-groovyshell-exception-in-thread-main#comment18958559_13763451

Comment: Neither your nor Hiery Nomus answers work any more, but the problem is still there. Whatever `configurations.addToClassLoader` used to be, it doesn't exist anymore. I don't understand exactly what classes did this have to load.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to do this is the following:

```
buildScript {
  repositories { mavenCentral() }
  dependencies {
    classpath "commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2"
  }
}

def groovyShell = new GroovyShell()
....
```

This puts the commons-cli dependency on the classpath of the buildscript instead of on the classpath of the project to be built.

Comment: This should work as long as it's used together with `new GroovyShell(buildScript.classLoader)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments! I got excited when I read this, thinking that I had just missed the obvious. However, I tried it again, just to make sure, and it doesn't work. (Whoops - submitted too soon. I am editing this comment now...)

Comment: This answer sounded familiar as I am pretty sure I went down this route. I tried it again, just to make sure, and it doesn't work. :( Peter, I did indeed use the "new GroovyShell(buildscript.classloader)" after declaring a dependency as Hiery suggested. After my hours of "experimentation" the other day, I am inclined to think this has something to do with Groovy's native dependency, and inclusion, on certain pieces of the commons-cli, such as CliBuilder, but not all of it. I admit this is over my head, and it should be simpler than I've made it. :)

Comment: How do you specify several libraries on the classpath? I can get rid of the first ClassNotFoundException by specifying classpath like this, but then I get problems with other missing dependencies.